# Run a sql command against databases from table

Tags: sql-server, database

Before I start, I need to point out that I am a SQL noob. I can write basic statements, but anything past JOIN statements is probably fairly new to me.

That said, I have cobbled together a script that deletes records from tables. The script itself does what it needs to do; however, when I run this script, I change the "USE" line to whatever database is next, stepping through databases manually. I use a command which populates a temporary table with a list of database names as reference.

How can I run my script against each database name in the temporary table directly, preferably all from a single stored procedure?

Comment: We don't need all the gory details of how long your script takes, and what it does, when your asking how to execute it against multiple databases. Concise questions do better than rambling ones.

Comment: Apologies; I've edited out all but the most relevant information.

Comment: That's much better :)

Comment: If you want to avoid cursors, you can consider the undocumented sp_MSForeachDb (http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one option is that you can use a cursor to grab all the database names (exclude databases you don't want to execute on), and use dynamic sql to execute for each database. It unfortunately has to be "dynamic" since you can't just do a while loop, `USE @dbname` `/*your magic code*/` `Fetch Next from MyCursor into @dbname`... It errors out when trying to do `USE @dbname`, So you actually *do* have to use `exec @variable` in it.

```
DECLARE @dbname varchar(max)
DECLARE @executeme nvarchar(max)
DECLARE DBCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT Name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name not in ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb'); --add additional exclusions here
OPEN DBCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM DBCursor INTO @dbname;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      SET @executeme = 
         N'use '+@dbname+'
           --YOUR SCRIPT HERE
         '
      EXEC sp_executesql @executeme
      FETCH NEXT FROM DBCursor into @dbname;
   END;
    CLOSE DBCursor;
DEALLOCATE DBCursor;
GO
```

This is going to loop across all databases, execute your script in each, until there is none left in the list of databases.  You can exclude certain databases in the select statement for the cursor (like the master, etc.) and add in any additional logic as you see fit for excluding.

Additionally, you can implement this in a stored procedure, so all you have to do is run the stored procedure, sit back and drink your favorite drink while it does the heavy lifting for you ;)

Comment: I won't have access to try this until tomorrow, but: My script uses "GO" in it; would this allow that? I can take it out if it doesn't.

Comment: @ArmanX You know, I'm not sure on that.  Never had the opportunity to test that.  I imagine it will work, but I definitely could be wrong.  Hope it works for you tomorrow!

Comment: I did have to make one change to your code: it looks like sp_execuesql requires ntext, nchar, or nvarchar. That change was enough to make my code work. Thanks! Also, it looks like 'GO' works inside the script, too.

Comment: @ArmanX Thanks for sharing the info about GO.  Glad it worked out for you!